# Create growing lines with changing colors using css3

Tags: jquery, css

I was creating a new website . I have few headers(h1,h2,h3,h4).I want to underline  the headers . These underlines should have the growing and color changing effects   like the ones found in : http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/.

Is there way to achieve these effects in css/jquery/html .

I dont know svg or flash animation.

Comment: Please add _complete_ and _relevant_ code. Try `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { text-decoration: underline; }`

Comment: @Tushar  if i use underline property that will be static . is it possible to get effects like the ones found in that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hark here is 'Ye Ol' [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xp1hdukq/1/). Witness the power of css. This one is simple and not sure what your end result desired is but hope this gets you going in the right direction.

```
.header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header > div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.redLine {
    height: 10px;
    animation: moveLine 3s infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
.blueLine {
    height: 10px;
    animation: moveLine 3s infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.greenLine {
    height: 10px;
    animation: moveLine 3s infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes moveLine {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    38% {
        z-index: 3;
    }
    39% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    70% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    71% {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 1;
        width: 110%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur guidance

Comment: Most welcome. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks ALFmachine for your example . I learned many things . Is it possible to make the lines grow from the middle in both directions( grow towards right and left simultaneaously ) and change color when they reach their 100% width like the ones in http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/ .

Comment: Most welcome. Glad to be of help! Here is an updated (JS Fiddle)[https://jsfiddle.net/xp1hdukq/3/]. It grows out from the middle now.
Just added left: 50%; and left left: -40px; at the beginning and end of the keyframes animation

Comment: for some reason fiddle pasted wrong... here is da link. https://jsfiddle.net/xp1hdukq/2/